# Why Blank Output in Debian Mathematica with Intel Graphics?

Tags: debian, intel-graphics, mathematica

I am experimenting my Debian 8.5 Intel graphics with Mathematica 11 student edition, and I cannot find a reason why many of the basic graphic objects are blank, although I have cleared (`Clear[pic]`) objects and killed the kernel (`Quit kernel`) from the menu *Evaluation* again and again. 
Test code

```
pic = Image[{{0., 1., 0.}, {1., 0., 1.}, {0., 1., 0.}}];
(* https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SurfaceData.html > last Neat Example*)
With[{surf = 
   SurfaceData[Entity["Surface", "PeriodicSurface"], 
     "ParametricEquations"][1]}, 
 ParametricPlot3D[surf[u, v], {u, -0.4, 0.4}, {v, -0.4, 0.4}, 
  PlotStyle -> Texture[pic], MeshStyle -> Opacity[0.15], Axes -> None,
   Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]]
```

Fig. 1 Blank Output and Expected example on Left-hand-side and Right-hand-side, respectively

[image]

OS: Debian 8.5
Linux kernel: 4.6 of backports
Hardware: Asus Zenbook UX303UA
Mathematica: 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Mathematica 11.0 on Linux systems. 
Mathematica 11.0.1 came out which cleans up the situation, but there has been now serious network problems for the distribution of the latest software to engineers for a couple of days, so I have not managed to troubleshoot further.

My initial test case was accepted by Wolfram for further troubleshooting of the case in 3D objects on Linux.